# Add "Delivery Time" to Product Page [Magento2]

Tags: magento2

I would like to edit a file where I can add the attribute "delivery_time" to the product page view so my customers can see the shipping / delivery times right away when checking out the product.
How can I do this / Where is that file I need to edit located?

Thanks alot!! :)))
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding at this file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phml

Here you can add code like : echo $_product->getDeliveryTime();

And make sure attribute are Used in Product Listing.

Comment: Okey. What would I need to put there, what kinda code? thx!

Comment: Try to be more describing your answer @Feedlay

Comment: You can write there like $product->getDeliveryTime()